# How to multiply the values of two arrays that have different shapes

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have two datasets `mask` and `precip_subset`. Both datasets were created in a similar fashion:

mask:

```
datapath = r"C:\Users\matth\Downloads\mask_global_0.25deg.nc"
f = Dataset(datapath)
print(f)

latbounds = [ -45 , -10 ]
lonbounds = [ 105, 160 ] 
lats = f.variables['lat'][:] 
lons = f.variables['lon'][:]

# latitude lower and upper index
latli = np.argmin( np.abs( lats - latbounds[0] ) )
latui = np.argmin( np.abs( lats - latbounds[1] ) ) 

# longitude lower and upper index
lonli = np.argmin( np.abs( lons - lonbounds[0] ) )
lonui = np.argmin( np.abs( lons - lonbounds[1] ) )

mask = f.variables['mask'][ lonli:lonui , latli:latui ]
```

precip_subset:

```
data_path = r"C:\Users\matth\Downloads\TRMM_3B42RT\3B42RT_Daily.201001.7.nc4"
f = Dataset(data_path)

latbounds = [ -45 , -10 ]
lonbounds = [ 105, 160 ] 
lats = f.variables['lat'][:] 
lons = f.variables['lon'][:]

# latitude lower and upper index
latli = np.argmin( np.abs( lats - latbounds[0] ) )
latui = np.argmin( np.abs( lats - latbounds[1] ) ) 

# longitude lower and upper index
lonli = np.argmin( np.abs( lons - lonbounds[0] ) )
lonui = np.argmin( np.abs( lons - lonbounds[1] ) )

precip_subset = f.variables['precipitation'][ : , lonli:lonui , latli:latui ]
```

The shapes of each dataset are `(1, 220, 140)` and `(1, 31, 220, 140)`. The last two elements in each dataset represent the latitude and longitude, respectively. The second element in `precip_subset` represents the day in the month of January.

Basically, I want to multiply the value of `mask` at each latitude/longitude by the value of `precip_subset` at each latitude/longitude in the 31 days. The value of `mask` is either `1` or `0`, depending on if the latitude/longitude is over water. I ultimately want to "mask" the values in `precip_subset` that are over water by multiplying it by zero.

Obviously, the shapes of the arrays are different. Does anyone know what I can do to achieve what I want to do?

EDIT: I was thinking about maybe utilizing a `for` loop, but I'm not sure how to construct that.

Comment: Have you tried `mask*precip_subset`. Numpy will broadcast this and it should be fine. See [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) at genereal broadcasting rules.

Comment: And please make minimal examples, as far as I can see your question is mainly about the multiplying two arrays, I guess we don't even have to know about the lattitude and how these array were built

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `x.shape` is `(1, 220, 140)` and `y.shape` is `(1, 31, 220, 140)`

```
x[:,None,:,:] * y
```

should work.  This acts as though `x` was replicated 31 times along the (new) 2nd axis.

Actually

```
x * y
```

will also work, since the (1,220,140) shape is expanded to `(None,1,220,140)` and on to `(1,31,220,140)`.  But if the first dimension was something different from `1` we'd need to explicit `None` to match the `31`.

That gets me wondering whether the shapes aren't really `(220, 140)` and `(31, 220, 140)`.  I haven't followed the construction in enough detail to see whether the initial size 1 dimension is significant or not.